# Release memory from elipsis argument (...)

Tags: r

My function take elipsis argument (...).
Once this is parsed, how can I release it from memory ?

```
rm(...)
```

or

```
rm(list(...))
```

do not works

Comment: Don't you save this argument somewhere within the function? Something like `args <- list(...)`?

Comment: Once you call `rm` on an object it is decoupled from memory. This will be cleared either when R is closed or more memory is demanded - it will be overwritten by new object(s).